# NodeJS How can i make my route out of middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nodes

I have some routes on my API. And have a middleware. Its creating bearer token and checking it. But i want some of my routes dont enter to that middleware so i can access without token. How can i make it ? My middleware :

```
  app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    req.path === "/api/v1/collection/byhome" ||  // I dont want that part.
    req.path === "/api/v1/user/login" // Its working but its not looks like best solution.
  ) {
    next();
  } else {
    const bearerHeader = req.header("authorization");
    if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
      const bearerToken = bearer[1];
      req.token = bearerToken;

      jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.SECRETKEY, async (err, authData) => {
        if (err) {
          res.sendStatus(401);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 400;
      const Response = {
        message: "Invalid Token",
        StatusCode: res.statusCode,
      };

      res.json(Response);
    }
  }
});
```

My Route :

```
app.get(
  `/api/${version}/article/bycollection/:id`,
  ArticleRoute.getbycollection
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your way of doing it is correct you can make your code more readable by making an array of all the middleware you want to be out of scope of your middleware

```
const whiteListEndpoints = ["/api/v1/this", "/api/v1/this1", "/api/v1/this2"]
```

then

```
// your middleware
app.use((req, res,next) => {
    //if the path was in the whitelist just call next function
    if(whiteListEndpoints.includes(req.url)) return next()

    // let the middlware do it's job
})
```

or you can change your express `use` order

```
const firstRoute = app.use("/no_middleware", router);

app.use((req, res, next) => {}) // your middleware

const secondRoute = app.use("/with_middleware", router);
```

here the first router won't use the middleware since it has not yet been called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Express.Router` to achieve the desired result. With express router you can differentiate between routes and have different middlewares for each router.

Follow the steps given below:

0. Create a auth middleware `middlewares/private.authenticate.js`

```js
function auth(req, res, next) {
    // do auth stuff...
    next();
}
```

1. Create a file `routes/private/index.js`

```js
// private route handler
import { Router } from "express";
import auth from "./middlewares/private.authenticate.js";

const router = Router();

router.use(auth); // use auth middleware

router.route("/")
    .get()
    .put()

export default router;
```

2. Create a file `routes/public/index.js`

```js
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

router.route("/")
    .get()
    .put()

export default router;
```

3. Your express app file

```js
import express from "express";
const app = express();

import PublicRoutes from "./routes/public";
import PrivateRoutes from "./routes/private";

// public routes path
app.use("/api/public", PublicRoutes);
// private routes path
app.use("/api/private", PrivateRoutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a route `express.Router()` and set this to a `path`, this router have all auth, then create a second `express.Router()` and this without auth.

```
var router = express.Router();
// your code for API auth...
router.get('/api/v1/collection/byhome',myMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hey There');
})
app.use('/api', router);
var routerGuest = express.Router();
//
routerGuest.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hey There');
})
app.use('/guest', routerGuest)
```

for authentication, I recomend to make a separate middleware and then pass it to our route

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next){
const bearerHeader = req.header("authorization");
if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
      const bearerToken = bearer[1];
      req.token = bearerToken;

      jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.SECRETKEY, async (err, authData) => {
        if (err) {
          res.sendStatus(401);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 400;
      const Response = {
        message: "Invalid Token",
        StatusCode: res.statusCode,
      };

      res.json(Response);
    }
  }
}
```

I think with this you may have some idea to do it :)